# how to reference dll in GAC in a remote machine in 3 tier structure

Tags: remoting, gac, com+

I have  a 3 tier structure in my office and my dll (in GAC) in business tier is already installed in my business component server .

Method 1: Remote GAC
I'm trying to build a light-weight application and the application will reference the dll in the remote business tier server, but I don't know how.

Method 2: old way DCOM or COM+
But I do find an old way by using DCOM (no more GAC). 
http://www.kepware.com/Support_Center/SupportDocuments/DCOM_Secure_by_default.pdf 
It seems relatively achievable, but after i follow the steps, I always get some security alert, such as no access.

Method 3: Web Service, too slow!
I do not want to use web service because I need fast access within LAN. web service is just too slow as it has to go through IIS.

Method 4: .NET remoting using TCP
This method seems to be faster than web service, but it seems to have a lot of overhead.

I don't mind use old technology as long as it works.
GAC make my dll more secure as it cannot be copied and used by other unauthorized people, so it is preferred.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I research quite some articles and it seems in order to have most of the benefit included(version control, security, convenience, pooling etc.), then
the best way is to **GAC** the dll in remote machine and then use **Regsvcs** to register the dll as **COM+** service.

some people don't want so much trouble as convenience is their top priority (fast deploy, security, version control are not that essential) then they suggest I can just XCopy the dll to remote server and then just **Regsvcs** it.